# Read textfile, process contents and send back as email with python

Tags: python, unicode, sendmail

I'm kind of desperate. I have a textfile containing German Umlauts, like "äöüÄÖÜ", which I need to read into my python script, process it and send back the processed information back via email.

The input textfile is:

```
ÄÖÜöäüß
```

The output in my Gmail-Account is

```
Ã„Ã–ÃœÃ¶Ã¤Ã¼ÃŸ
```

My script is:

```
import re, datetime, json, smtplib, ssl
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

with open('sample.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
port = 587  # For starttls
sender_email = "ENTER SENDER GMAIL HERE"
password = "ENTER PASSWORD HERE"

recipient = "ENTER RECIPIENT GMAIL HERE"

# Create a secure SSL context
context = ssl.create_default_context()

# Try to log in to server and send email
try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,port)
    server.starttls(context=context) # Secure the connection
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    message = MIMEText(data.encode("utf-8"), _charset="utf-8")
    server.sendmail(sender_email, recipient, message.as_string("utf-8"))
    print("Email has been sent.")
except Exception as e:
    # Print any error messages to stdout
    print(e)
finally:
    server.quit()
```

I just removed my password and the emailadress and the proccess within as it is not relevant.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe add "encoding='utf-8'" or "encoding='utf-8-sig' to the parameters of the open() method, with which you read in the text file

Comment: THAT did the job. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you want to debug this yourself, you can print the contents of "data" mid-script. That way you can narrow down if the error stems from the email sending part of the script, or the reading part of it.